# C++ boost::bind with std::shared_ptr trowing operation canceled on timeout handler

Tags: c++, asynchronous, boost, boost-asio

I´m trying to build an asynchronous server using `boost::asio`.

The server is read only and needs to have a session timeout: If a session passes more than N seconds without 
receiving data, the session is disconnected and the client needs to start the connection again.

**SocketServer.hpp**

```
class SocketServer {

    public:
        SocketServer(boost::asio::io_service& service);
        virtual ~SocketServer();
        void StartAsync(int port);
        void StopAsync();

    private:
        void StartAccept();
        void HandleAccept(std::shared_ptr<SocketSession> session, const boost::system::error_code& errorCode);

        boost::asio::io_service &ioService;
        boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor acceptor;
};
```

**SocketServer.cpp**

```
SocketServer::SocketServer(boost::asio::io_service& service) :
                    ioService(service),
                    acceptor(service) {}

SocketServer::~SocketServer() {}

void SocketServer::StartAsync(int port)
{
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint ep(boost::asio::ip::tcp::v4(), port);

    acceptor.open(ep.protocol());
    acceptor.set_option(boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor::reuse_address(true));
    acceptor.bind(ep);

    StartAccept();
}

void SocketServer::StopAsync()
{
    acceptor.cancel();
}

void SocketServer::StartAccept()
{
    std::shared_ptr<SocketSession> session = std::shared_ptr<SocketSession>(new SocketSession(ioService));
    acceptor.listen();
    acceptor.async_accept(session->getSessionSocket(), boost::bind(&SocketServer::HandleAccept, this, session, boost::asio::placeholders::error));
}

void SocketServer::HandleAccept(std::shared_ptr<SocketSession> session, const boost::system::error_code& errorCode)
{
    std::stringstream ss;

    if (errorCode)
    {
        std::cout << "Error accepting incoming connection: Error: " << boost::system::system_error(errorCode).what();
    }
    else
    {
        ss << "Connection accepted from address " << socket.remote_endpoint().address().to_string() << ".";
        session->start();
    }

    StartAccept();
}
```

**SocketSession.hpp**

```
#define MAX_BUFFER_LENGTH 1024

class SocketSession {

    public:
        SocketSession(boost::asio::io_service& service);
        virtual ~SocketSession();

        void start();
        void startTimeoutHandler();
        void HandleRead(size_t bytesTransferred, const boost::system::error_code& errorCode);
        boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket& getSessionSocket();

    private:
        boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket sessionSocket;
        char readBuffer[MAX_BUFFER_LENGTH];
        boost::asio::deadline_timer readTimeout;
        void TimeoutHandler(const boost::system::error_code& errorCode);
};
```

**SocketSession.cpp**

```
SocketSession::SocketSession(boost::asio::io_service& service) :
    sessionSocket(service),
    readTimeout(service) {}

SocketSession::~SocketSession() {}

void SocketSession::start()
{
    startTimeoutHandler();
    sessionSocket.async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer(readBuffer, MAX_BUFFER_LENGTH), boost::bind(&SocketSession::HandleRead, this, boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred, boost::asio::placeholders::error));
}

void SocketSession::startTimeoutHandler()
{
    readTimeout.expires_from_now(boost::posix_time::seconds(10));
    readTimeout.async_wait(boost::bind(&SocketSession::TimeoutHandler, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error));
}

void SocketSession::HandleRead(size_t bytesTransferred, const boost::system::error_code& errorCode)
{
    std::stringstream ss;

    readTimeout.expires_from_now(boost::posix_time::seconds(10));

    if (errorCode)
    {
        std::cout << "Error reading data for session: Error: " << boost::system::system_error(errorCode).what();
        delete this;
    }
    else
    {
        std::string data(readBuffer, bytesTransferred);
        std::cout << "Data read:" << data << std::endl;
    }

    start();
}

{
    return sessionSocket;
}

void SocketSession::TimeoutHandler(const boost::system::error_code& errorCode)
{
    delete this;
}
```

This compiles fine,

My problem here is the session returns the following error once it is loaded:
 `Error: Operation canceled` at the `SocketSession::HandleRead`.

It seens that boost::bind doesn´t like my `std::shared_ptr`. I tried a version changing it to normal pointers and the server works fine.

So, here goes my questions:

Is it possible to work on `boost::bind` with `std::shared_ptr` ?

If yes, am I doing that in the correct way ?

What may be causing my code to exit without listening to the client ?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (_"why isn't this code working?"_) must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: The code is running, but as stated above is throwing an error on execution. I will elaborate.